# Vectorized cummulative sum based on value in array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-science

I'm looking a vectorized way to do a cummulative sum that resets everytime a 0 occurs. For instance say we have an array `ar = np.array([0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0])`. The output i want is then `np.array([0,1,0,1,2,0,1,0])`.

I have the following implementations that works but they are not completely vectorized.

```
Method 1:
s = pd.Series(ar)
data = s.groupby(s.eq(0).cumsum()).cumsum().tolist()

Method 2:
def intervaled_cumsum(ar):
    split = np.array((np.split(ar, np.where(ar<1)[0])))[1:]
    sizes = np.array([len(i) for i in split])
    out = ar.copy()

    arc = ar.cumsum()
    idx = sizes.cumsum()

    out[idx[0]] = ar[idx[0]] - arc[idx[0]-1]
    out[idx[1:-1]] = ar[idx[1:-1]] - np.diff(arc[idx[:-1]-1])

    return out.cumsum()
```

How might i do this in python using any library really, could be something other than numpy?

shout out to the answers on this thread [Multiple cumulative sum within a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178977/multiple-cumulative-sum-within-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Method 2 looks familiar! So, the little loop `sizes = np.array([len(i) for i in split])` in an otherwise vectorized approach is your bottleneck?

Comment: @Divakar [Hah, so does method 1!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48805093/4909087)

Comment: Oh the methods are basically taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178977/multiple-cumulative-sum-within-a-numpy-array. Sorry for not giving credit where its due! @Divakar

Comment: @hedge I recommend looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816598/4909087) for performant methods and alternatives.

Comment: So if youre coming to python from Matlab vectorization doesn't really work the same way in python. in Matlab you need to vectorize almost every single thing to get performance, but sometime in python (even in numpy or similar packages) the vectorization is more for convenience than for performance.

Comment: If you really need performance I'd consider using Cython here. I think its a good problem for it, and you should see large gains from it.

Comment: @Divakar i think you may have linked to the wrong post. it doesnt seem to be a duplicate of this one? maybe you meant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178977/multiple-cumulative-sum-within-a-numpy-array

Comment: @GrantWilliams The accepted answer to the linked dup Q&A does it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44421252/. And as asked in the question is fully vectorized.